# sidekiq getting delay in job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sendgrid

I have scheduled a job using sidekiq to send an email to userbefore call of 1 hr. (Ex - if they set call for 3 pm the email should send at 2 pm)

```
email_reminder = EmailReminderWorker.perform_at((call.suggest_time.accepted_time - 1.hours), call.id)
```

But am getting mail with 7 to 8 minutes delay please advice because of sidekiq or send-grid am getting this delay and how to overcome this issue

Comment: Did you notice that every single page which sends you an email (such as password reset page) says "we sent you an email, it should arrive within several minutes. If it didn't arrive after 15 minutes, check your spam folder or contact us"? Email is not instantaneous, it may take a few minutes.

Comment: So it is not possible to send a mail with exactly 1 hr difference, always there must be some time difference is that am correct?

Comment: Exactly-exactly, like down to the second exactly - yes, this is not possible.

Comment: I mean, if the stars align, it _might_ happen. But it's not guaranteed and you shouldn't count on it.

Comment: Using sidekiq am sending sms too, here also am facing the same time differences. Is that happened because of sidekiq?

Comment: "Is that happened because of sidekiq" - I have no idea. Watch your sidekiq logs, it will show exact timestamps of when  it starts and finishes a job.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Are your clocks sync'd and accurate?

Comment: am using sidekiq(4.2.9)